# How to plot multiple coordinates using a while loop? How does a while loop work?

Tags: java, loops, while-loop, coordinates

I need to modify this method so that I can enter multiple points for x and y using a while loop. If the value is out of range of 0 - 290 then the loop needs to exit and print "Done". I just learned while loops and I still don't totally understand how they work. This is my code for that method so far.

```
/**
 * Plot points method.
 * @param keyboard scanner
 */
public void plotPoints(Scanner keyboard)
{
    System.out.print("Enter an x and y coordinate: ");

    //Read x from user
    int x = keyboard.nextInt();
    //Read y from user
    int y = keyboard.nextInt();



    while ( x > 0 || x < 290 || y > 0 || y < 290)
    {
        //Plot the point 
        new Circle(x,y); 


        if (x < 0 || x > 290 || y < 0 || y > 290 )
            System.out.println("Done.");
            break;
    }


}
```

Comment: What do you not understand about them? It's hard to answer this question without knowing what specifically is giving you trouble. What [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/while.html) have you read, and what if any is unclear in it?

Comment: How to end the loop and how to restart it so that it re-asks the question after plotting one of the points.

Comment: The stuff that gets repeatedly run is only the stuff within the `{...}` block for the `while`. So if you want to ask the user a question again, or re-read values for `x` or `y`, you need to put the code to do that within the `{...}` block.

Answer (score 0):

if X and Y are coordinates then you should reorganize the conditions in the two tests (while & if) because you get an (X,Y) pair...

And the process that changes the values of (x,y) is missing. => This is a limitless loop :)